# SSH hostname used is different than what hostname returns

Tags: linux, ssh, hostname

I use PuTTY to SSH into a remote server by putting "SomeComputerName" into the Host Name box of PuTTY.

Then when I run the `hostname` command at the termainal I get something different like "abc.somestuff.com".

Why is the name used with PuTTY different than what `hostname` returns?

Comment: What you refer to as `SomeComputerName` has an entry with the DNS server you are using. You can confirm this by simply running something like `ping SomeComputerName` in your terminal, the IP you see is what your DNS server returned. The hostname that the server self-identifies with is often the same as a DNS record, but it doesn't have to be, since it is just that: self-identifying, with no built in authentication or verification. Also, by modifying your local `hosts` file on both Windows and Linux, you can map any host name to any IP, overriding DNS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the name you use to connect to a system using SSH is its DNS name. any given system can have 0 to many DNS names assigned to its IP addresses. The constraint is that DNS names must be globally unique (with the exception of non-public domains like `.local`).

System hostnames however are singular (there can be only one for the system). That said though, hostnames need not be unique beyond the local network. so you can have a server named server1 and so can I.

So, there is no requirement that you connect to the system using the same name as its configured hostname.

There is no way to tell why the admins of the system choose not to use the same names for both the system and the network naming service (DNS). There is simply no requirement that they do so.

In my shop, we replace servers periodically, but we don't want to change or reconfigure our applications that use services on that server, so we have the apps point to a DNS name (webdev, webtest, datatest, etc). then when we create a new server to set it up, we have to give it a new name (cause the old server is still there), but once the new one is ready we just point the DNS name to the new server's IP address, or move the IP from the old server to the new one to complete the replacement.

Comment: What linux commands are used to show the mapping of DNS names to system hostnames?

Comment: DNS maps names to IP addresses, so there is no mapping of names to hostnames. they are of completely different scope and have nothing to do with eachother. I can name the system 'blah' with the IP 192.168.1.1, and then put in a DNS name like 'data.example.com' that points to 192.168.1.1.  then clients can connect to the server using data.example.com. you could then replace that server with one named 'blah1', but keep the IP 192.168.1.1, and the name data.example.com will point to the new server with no changes. DNS and hostnames are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

An addendum to Franks answer, check if there’s any custom alias in your ssh config.

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does PuTTY use `ssh_config`?